# How to add an alert dialog that extends AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I can add an alert dialog if I don't want to add a button in the alert dialog. But when I want to add an alert dialog that has 2 buttons in the 'onPostExecute' it shows red line when I type this code:

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

The error that shows in red line:

> Cannot resolve method 'makeText(anonymous android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener, java.lang.String, int)'

I followed the tutorial in this link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW_nvmmxURc

This is my code in my post execute:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (type.equals("cleck")){
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("PUV Checker");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Sample");


        }else {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Comment");

        }

        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

**Note:** I am a complete beginner, just compiling ideas in different tutorials

EDIT: Added the whole code

```
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

/**
 * Created by Julian on 7/21/2017.
 */

public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void, String> {
    String type;
    Context context;
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){
        context = ctx;

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        type = params[0];
        String register_url = "http://10.0.2.2/insert_comment";
        String retrieve_id = "http://10.0.2.2/rizal3.php";
        String report_id = "http://10.0.2.2/rizal4.php";
        if (type.equals("button")) {
            try {
                String id = params[1];
                String comment = params[2];
                String rating = params[3];
                URL url = new URL(register_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("id", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(id, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("comment", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(comment, "UTF-8") + "&"
                        + URLEncoder.encode("rating", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(rating, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else if(type.equals("cleck")) {
            try {
                String id_ret = params[1];

                URL url = new URL(retrieve_id);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("PLATE_NUM", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(id_ret, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                String result = "";
                String line = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(type.equals("report")){
                try {
                    String id_ret = params[1];
                    String puv_type = params[2];
                    String report = params[3];

                    URL url = new URL(report_id);
                    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                    httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                    OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                    String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("PLATE_NUM","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(id_ret,"UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("PUV_TYPE", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(puv_type, "UTF-8") + "&"
                            + URLEncoder.encode("content", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(report, "UTF-8");;
                    bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                    bufferedWriter.flush();
                    bufferedWriter.close();
                    outputStream.close();
                    InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
                    String result = "";
                    String line = "";
                    while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                        result += line;
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    inputStream.close();
                    httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                    return result;
                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
        return null;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (type.equals("cleck")){
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("PUV Checker");
            alertDialog.setMessage("Sample");


        }else {
            alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setTitle("Comment");

        }

        alertDialog.setMessage(result);
        alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                Toast.makeText(this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
        alertDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Where I call the background worker:

```
public void Button(View view) {

        String puv_plate = report_plate.getText().toString();
        String puv_type = report_type.getText().toString();
        String content = report_content.getText().toString();
        String type="report";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(Report.this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, puv_plate,puv_type,content);
    }
```

Edit:

The Error that I get when I use this line

```
Toast.makeText(BackgroundWorker.this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

> Cannot resolve method 'makeText(rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion.BackgroundWorker,java.lang.String,int)'

EDIT:

The whole code in the Report.java (Where I call the BackgroundWorker)

```
package rjj.manilapuvtravelcompanion;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Report extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText report_plate, report_type, report_content;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_report);

        report_plate =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.report_plate_num);
        report_type = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.report_puv_type);
        report_content =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.report_content);
    }

    public void Button(View view) {

        String puv_plate = report_plate.getText().toString();
        String puv_type = report_type.getText().toString();
        String content = report_content.getText().toString();
        String type="report";
        BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(Report.this);
        backgroundWorker.execute(type, puv_plate,puv_type,content);
    }
}
```

Comment: **this** is the problem I suppose. Pass the Activity Context

Comment: ActivityName.this instead of this in Toast.makeText(this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

> public static Toast makeText (Context context, CharSequence text, int
>   duration)

You should pass **[context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)** .

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This
>   is an abstract class whose implementation is provided by the Android
>   system .

```
Toast.makeText(context, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Code will be

```
 alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
    if (type.equals("cleck"))
    {
       alertDialog.setTitle("PUV Checker");
       alertDialog.setMessage("Sample");
    }
    else
    {
       alertDialog.setTitle("Comment");
       alertDialog.setMessage(result);
    }

 alertDialog.setButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
 {
    @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        });

    alertDialog.show();
```

Answer (score 0):

You giving DialogInterface.OnCLickListener refernce instead of context.
So do this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: REd word or method when I typed 'getApplicationContext()'

Answer (score 0):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

use Activity.this is working if your code is in activity.

Comment: use **context** place of **MainActivity.this**

Answer (score 0):

Try using below instead of passing this`

```
Toast.makeText(<YourMainActivity>.this,`...
```

You can also use getApplicationContext() or getBaseContext(), however it is not advisable to use them, unless the application context is required.

Comment: Consider passing the context of your activity (Activity.this) to the constructor of your BackgroundWorker subclass and saving it as a member variable for this purpose.

Comment: Can you please show me how to do that, I really am a newbie in programming.

Comment: I see you already have a constructor in BackgroundWorker that accepts the context parameter. 

1. You need to check if you are passing the correct parameter in the Activity Class which is creating this AsyncTask
BackgroundWorker task = new BackgroundWorker(YourActivity.this)

Pass the saved context while making the toast. 
2. Toast.makeText(context, "Yes", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Hope this works.

Comment: @YahjRodriguez any luck ?